# instagram story layout collection view swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, header, instagram, collectionview

I was wondering how to better set up a UI: the goal is to accomplish a instagram feed-like interface such as this one : [image: instagram]

From what I've inspected it seems to be a `collectionView` with a header, in that header is placed a horizontal collection view for all the stories (circle elements).

If I set a `collectionView` inside a `viewController's view` I can use the controller to kind of mediate between the view (collectionView) and the model (firestore backend) using MVC.

If I set a horizontal `collectionView` inside the header that I set up in this way:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    
    return headerView
}
```

How can I communicate between the `viewcontroller` and the `collectionview's header`? using a delegate? I don't know which is the best solution since using a header doesn't seem the best option to me.

If you have a better option I would be really happy to listen.

Comment: why do you want to use a `headerView` ? Did you try only using a `horizontal CollectionView` and a simple `UIView` with a `UILabel` ("Story")  and a `UIButton` ("watch all") above it ?

Comment: because the feed needs to scroll in up and down direction as well, so I need a vertical collection view, in which I need to embed a horizontal one on the top for the stories feature

Comment: why dont you must `constraint` the `vertical CollectionView`  to the `bottomConstraint` of the `topView` ?

Comment: great point, I thought about it too, but the thing is I want the horizontal collection view to scroll together with the vertical one, if I do this the top view remains stuck at the top of the view controller

Comment: what do you mean by *scroll together* ? Why cant you constraint the vertical one to the horizontal one ? This way the horizontal view stays at the top and the vertical one stays to the bottom of the horizontal one

Comment: because as you are saying If I scroll down the vertical one, the horizontal won't follow the scroll, because it's not part of the vertical one. If I want to embed the horizontal collection view controller inside the header I should use some kind of view controller containment but I don' t think it's the right thing to do with reusable header views

Comment: Maybe I’m high but I really don’t know what you’re trying to achieve ... :D

Comment: you're not high ahah it's me, I couldn't express what I thinking.
Anyway now I managed to solve the problem: basically I was thinking about "embedding" a horizontal collectionviewcontroller  inside the header because in this way I could use life cycles methods to make API calls to the server. now I did it and it works, so no need for using constraints to separate the 2 collection views

Comment: Ok haha congrats to you :D